# Is it possible to disable some particular sections in Doughnut chart in chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am having a scenario where I have to make some sections of Doughnut chart, clickable and some non-clickable and disabled in chart.js.

Any solution would be much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: hey anp what do you mean by a disable. Which features you want to disable. Give some brief explanation and code if apply here.

Comment: Suppose we have sliced Doughnut chart, where I have to perform some task on click event. But also want to restrict some slices that are not clickable. and produces no action.

Comment: You can apply the different functions of jquery or javascript on different slice. Actually chart.js is itself a javascript. so in each slice you can have that function. May be i am wrong because i have not fully read its documentation.